# Wrong calculation with reduce

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, callback, reduce

Can someone explain why this equals 052 and not 7? I simply dont get it.

```
 products: [
            {id: 1, name: 'Baju', Hours: 2},
            {id: 2, name: 'Celena', Hours: 5}
            ],

 subTotalTest: function (){
            return this.products.reduce((total, item) => {
                return total + item.Hours
            },0)
```

When I call subTotalTest I get 052 and not 7 as I expect and want.

Comment: The code you posted would not do that, as all relevant values are definitely numbers and not strings.

Comment: Maybe elsewhere you're updating the "Hours" properties from `<input>` values, and that would mean they'd become strings and would have to be explicitly made into numbers.

Comment: Thank you! Excatly my issues. The parseInt() solved it.

Comment: Try converting `item.Hours` to a number before adding it to `total` like this `return total + Number(item.Hours)`

Comment: Thank Gabriel. As I pointed out this was excatly my problem. I solved it with parseInt()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The products array you're getting has 'Hours' as string and not integer, that is why its being concatenated and not added up.

Try this:

```
subTotalTest: function (){
        return this.products.reduce((total, item) => {
            return total + parseInt(item.Hours)
        },0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Including the radix parameter inside the parseInt would be a better practice

```
subTotalTest: function (){
        return this.products.reduce((total, item) => {
            return total + parseInt(item.Hours, 10)
        },0)
```